# Drop zones for skydiving in China

Tags: china, price, parachutes-skydiving

I would like to know about drop zones for skydiving in China.
What is average cost here in China for skydiving?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google yields the forum site [DropZone](http://www.dropzone.com/dropzone/Asia/China/) which lists 2 drop zones.

Normally the best place to start searching for things like this would be national associations though [China seem to lack such a body](http://skydiveasia.com/china/)